# Laravel validation non localized error messages

Tags: php, validation, laravel, localization

When using the Validator the error messages contain the localized version of the errors which is nice for displaying on a website. But in my API I want the non localized error messages to be displayed. E.g instead of `The :attribute field is required.` I would like `required` as the error.

How can I get the non-localized error messages from the validator?

Comment: Do you want the name of the rules that failed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the [Laravel Validation documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/validation) there is a example of this. Take a look at `Validating Multiple Fields` topic.

See:

```
if ($validator->fails())
{
    $messages = $validator->messages(); // get the messages
    $failed = $validator->failed(); // get the failed rules
}
```

I hope this helps.